# Masstransit How to disconnect from from RabbitMq

Tags: masstransit

I am using Masstransit with RabbitMQ. As part of some deployment procedure, At some point in time I need my service to disconnect and stop receiving any messages.

Assuming that I won't need the bus until the next restart of the service, will it be Ok to use bus.StopAsync()?

Is there a way to get list of end points and then remove them from listining ?

Answer (score 0):

You should `StopAsync` the bus, and then when ready, call `StartAsync` to bring it back up (or start it at the next service restart).

Comment: Thanks Chris.
Is it possible to disconnect only the receive end point and leave the option to continue publish messages?

Comment: Not really. You can only stop receive endpoints that are connected to the bus after it is started via ConnectReceiveEndpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To stop receiving messages without stopping the buss I needed a solution that will avoid the consume message pipeline from consuming any type of message. I tried with observers but unsuccessfully. My solution came up with custom consuming message filter.
The filter part looks like this

```
public class ComsumersBlockingFilter<T> :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        var scope = context.CreateFilterScope("messageFilter");
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        // Check if the service is degraded (true for this demo)
        var isServiceDegraded = true;
        if (isServiceDegraded)
        {
            //Suspend the message for 5 seconds
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), context.CancellationToken);

            if (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //republish the message
                await context.Publish(context.Message);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message {context.MessageId} has been republished");
            }

            // NotifyConsumed to avoid skipped message
            await context.NotifyConsumed(TimeSpan.Zero, "messageFilter");
        }
        else
        {
            //Next filter in the pipe is called
            await next.Send(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to delay with cancellation token and the republish the message. After that call contect.NotifyConsumed to avoid the next pipeline filters and return normally.